# Saying “You’re one of THOSE people” or “Not to be THAT guy...”

Tags: expressions, traduction

Is there any French way to say these expressions? They’re used to mean that someone does something extra annoying or is very particular and odd.

Like “You seriously eat your pizza with a fork? Ugh, you’re one of THOSE people.”

Or “Not to be that guy, but can you please not eat that around me? The smell makes my stomach ache.”

Is there anything like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are near équivalents and after some more thinking about the question you'll find certainly others besides those shown below ;

- “You seriously eat your pizza with a fork? Ugh, you’re one of THOSE people.”
  *« Tu manges vraiment ta pizza avec une fourchette ? ah, **tu es comme ça** ?*
- “Not to be that guy, but can you please not eat that around me? The smell makes my stomach ache.”
  *« Je ne **veux pas être du genre déplaisant**, mais pourriez-vous vous abstenir de manger ça quand je suis là ? L'odeur me retourne l'estomac.*

In a more formal level of expression, educated people might use the word "engeance", which rings with the English idiomatism ; however, typical forms using this word are quite often a means of expressing much contempt or eventually to add a humourous streak;

(*humourous streak*)

- “You seriously eat your pizza with a fork? Ugh, you’re one of THOSE people.”
  *« Tu manges vraiment ta pizza avec une fourchette ? ah, **tu es de cette engeance** ?*

Comment: thank you so much, this is perfect! i definitely never knew about “engeance” or “du genre déplaisant”!